# Sim card hosting?

Tags: hosting, sim-card

There are many companies which provides sim card hosting services for receiving sms, I wanna how is this possible (at the core level)? do they use any kinda protocol or any custom devices for forwarding text messages to there servers.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of SIM card hosting being offered, if it is Virtual SIM card hosting (VSIM) such as this https://www.world-text.com/services/virtual-sim-hosting/ then this is only achievable were the provider has a direct connection to a mobile network over SS7. This requires very specialist knowledge, software and hardware, but is a very reliable and fast option.

If however they are offering GSM modem based SIM card hosting such as this http://world-text.com/services/sim-hosting/ then this utilises GSM modems which are normally hosted in a data centre and communicated with over IP, with messages returned to the providers SMSC. This method is slower, and is of course reliant on a local cell tower signal to work.